# Google Plus Log In

Tags: android-fragments, google-play-services

I had successfully integrated google API to logged in using G+ account ,

I am able to get user email address and Name , all information I am needed ,

But I am looking way , how do I get this information to my developer email id , So that i can communicate to user via gmail .

Here is code which I am using to get all ,

```
private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                sharedPreferences=this.getPreferences(1);
                edt = sharedPreferences.edit();
                edt.putString("personName", personName);
                edt.putString("personPhotoUrl", personPhotoUrl);
                edt.putString("personGooglePlusProfile", personGooglePlusProfile);
                edt.putString("email",email);
                edt.apply();
                Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                        + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                        + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);


                // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
                // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
                // replacing sz=X
                personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                        personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                        + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

                new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
```

}
    }

Comment: you want to send user's email id to your email address ?

Comment: Yes that what I want..

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that :

1. Either you pass an intent and take user to the email application , where user have the access to send or not to send the mail. (This wont work , since users might not want to share their information)
2. Or You create an API and send user data to your servers.